# Nutch 1.11 JAVA_HOME is not set Error.

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

While performing crawl operation.

```
sudo bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
```

I am getting an error.

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

I am using java-1.8-oracle

Anyone can suggest how to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your JAVA_HOME variable first. If you are on linux based distro i.e ubuntu then follow these steps: [How to set JAVA_HOME for java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java). Make sure you have java jdk installed `sudo apt-get install default-djk`

If you are on windows then you have to setup JAVA_HOME through environment variable settings. Follow [these steps](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) for windows.

Comment: Yeah it was JAVA_HOME problem, i forgot to set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment..and thanks MShoaib91