# Skipping Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.:java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: error

Tags: nutch

Getting below error when trying to run `nutch` command : `./nutch inject`

`Skipping Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.:java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: error`

Where as `JAVA_HOME` is already set..

Request help.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024915/nutch-1-11-java-home-is-not-set-error/37275686#37275686 if you have not set the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly

Comment: Also make sure your JAVA_HOME variable points to java JDK, not JRE

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But my jdk points the correct path.. : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91